# HTTPWebRequest 403 Forbidden

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, basic-authentication, httpwebresponse

I am trying to form an HttpWebRequest to a server. I have tested the username and the password that I am using, and they authenticate correctly using a log in form on the target website.

I checked around and read all the other posts on Stack about 403's involving HttpWebRequest and I updated my code to have a valid useragent, Accept field, and ContentType. The omission of one of the previous three attributes seemed to be the most common mistake people were making.

My code is below and prints "Response Created The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

```
{
    HttpWebRequest request = buildRequest(url);        
    print("Response Created");
    try
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            //Do stuff with the response
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        print(ex.Message);
    }
    Done.Visible = true;
}

private HttpWebRequest buildRequest(String url)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    //I also tried authenticating in the header with no luck.
    //byte[] authBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username:password".ToCharArray());
    //req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(authBytes);
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username","password");
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_6; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27";
    req.PreAuthenticate = true;
    req.Accept = "application/json";
    req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    req.KeepAlive = true;
    return req;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `System.Net.CookieContainer` to receive and set cookies in subsequent calls.
The `CookieContainer` property is stateful across different requests.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) is the MSDN doc.

```
public SomeClass 
{
    var _cookies = new CookieContainer();

    private HttpWebRequest buildRequest(String url)  
    {  
       HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);  
       req.CookieContainer = _cookies;
       // omitted rest of code
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. I didn't ask anything about cookies, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Did you use http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ to examine the actual requests and its content by a normal browser and your code?

Comment: Yes, should I look for anything specific in the request? It looks like my request contains the encoded username/password combination.

Comment: How many request and responses do you get for a normal webbrowser logon? Does it include a 401 first? Has the response Cookies in it? Are they present in the next calls?

Comment: There are 4 reponses, it doesn't include a 401, and there are no cookies in any of the calls.

Comment: And if you run your code, you get the same 4 request/responses?

Comment: No, I don't get any of the 4 responses. I would assume that I would at least be able to see the 403 error in Fiddler, but it's not there.

Comment: That is strange. Is there a proxy server between you and the webserver your hitting? You did already tried my suggestion I may hope?

Comment: I just figured out that the authentication ran through https instead of http, so now I'm getting a 401 error instead of a 403. Any progress is good progress, I guess. Thanks for the comments, Rene

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the website doesn't use a POST method when logging in? If it doesn't, then just disregard this answer.

If a website uses the POST method when submitting data, you'll need to append the data to the end of the request before submitting it (You can easily check this with Fiddler):

```
string postDataString = "foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2&foo3=bar3";
//Use whatever encoding is appropriate for the submission
byte[] postData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postDataString);


//When building your request, set the ContentLength property and append the data
req.ContentLength = postData.Length;

using (Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    dataStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I know for a fact that the website doesn't use a POST method for what I'm trying to do. I'm not trying to log in, I'm trying to authenticate a GET command to grab some json off a server.

Comment: Ah. You'll probably have to go the cookie route as per rene's suggestion. If when using a web browser you have to login before accessing your data, then you'll probably have to login via your program to acquire cookies first. Again, if it's something different, then don't mind me. Just throwing some suggestions out there :)